# Nothing works to fix: Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift4, xcode9

Ok, I have absolutely no idea why this is occurring as I haven't updated Xcode or touched this project in a few weeks - this was AFTER Xcode had to install some "additional components" just now.

I am unable to compile because I have 1 pod (https://github.com/tinypass/piano-sdk-for-ios)

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.2

Originally I had the error

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2

As I hadn't migrated to Swift 4 but I thought doing so might fix the problem. No luck.

I have tried doing pod deintegrate, then pod install again. And I have tried pod update. I have cleaned many times.

My original pod file:

```
  # Pods for Adventures In Design

pod 'PianoOAuth', '~>2.0.2’ //THIS IS PROBLEM
pod 'AudioPlayerManager'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'DeckTransition', '~> 1.0'
```

But that is their most recent released version. How can I make my project compile here? I'm on Xcode 9.1 9B55

Comment: Did you find the solution for it. I am facing same issue "Module compiled with Swift 4.0.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler"